# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cvzone'

Tags: cvzone

I'm stuck on a probably stupid thing.
I try to run my code with cvzone but I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cvzone'
```

Although I have installed this package. I use Spyder.

My conf:

- python 3.9.1
- cvzone 1.5.5
- opencv-python 4.6.0.66

Any advice will be helpful.
Cheers

Comment: Has anyone had similar problem. I don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install cvzone
```

You can visit this link for more details
https://github.com/cvzone/cvzone

Answer (score 0):

solving the cvzone problem,try it.It worked for me 
(1)python3.10 -m pip install cvzone
(2)python3.10 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
(3)python3.10 -m pip install pyarrow

Answer (score -1):

pip install cvzone
used in pycharm

Comment: OP said that they already have cvzone installed, so trying to install it with pip probably wouldn't help. Also, in the future, please try to include a bit more detail in your answers.